# Why the local Jekyll code is different from the one uploaded to github?

Tags: html, css, jekyll

I found one of my blog pages is different from the one that I've seen in the local server. So I call out the HTML code and found there is something different.

The one in local server:

```
<li>
   <a target="_blank" href="http://weibo.com">
     <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
       <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x">
         ::before
       </i>
       <i class="fa fa-weibo fa-stack-1x fa-inverse">
         ::before
       </i>
     </span>
   </a>
 </li>
```

The one in Github Pages:

```
<li>
   <a target="_blank" href="http://weibo.com">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
          <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-weibo fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
      </span>
   </a>
</li>
```

I fork this Jekyll template from others. And I've googled `::before` but I still don't understand it thoroughly. Can anybody tell me how to add `::before` to my `Github Pages` HTML code?

Comment: A code repository url can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

the `:before` and `:after` in css are pseudo-element.

A CSS pseudo-element is used to style specified parts of an element.

For example, it can be used to:

- Style the first letter, or line, of an element
- Insert content before, or after, the content of an element

You can see this `::before` and `::after` only on developer tools.

In this case you are using some icons and this icons are using `:before`.

If your icons are fine so the `:before` is working.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp

Comment: Thank you. But I don't know why I can see `::before` when using my local server but after the code has been uploaded that `::before` disappeared?

Comment: @Coding_Rabbit You should read some more about pseudo elements. They do not exist in your code but are rendered nevertheless.